# Using setcap in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04

To add the cap_net_raw capability to (for eg /bin/ping), we use the following:

```
#setcap cap_net_raw=ep /bin/ping
```

What is the meaning of ep and why is it required here ?

Comment: http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/capabilities.7.html and `man cap_from_text`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389879/how-to-set-capabilities-with-setcap-command

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This sets the `CAP_NET_RAW` bit in both the "effective" (e) and "permitted" (p) capability sets. These two sets, along with the "inheritable" set, govern the capabilities that a process has or can set.

See more here:

[capabilities - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities)

> Capability Sets
>
> Each thread has three capability sets containing zero or more of the
>   above capabilities:
>
> **`Effective`** - the capabilities used by the kernel to
>   perform permission checks for the thread.
>
> **`Permitted`** - the capabilities
>   that the thread may assume (i.e., a limiting superset for the
>   effective and inheritable sets). If a thread drops a capability from
>   its permitted set, it can never re-acquire that capability (unless it
>   exec()s a set-user-ID-root program).
>
> **`inheritable`** - the capabilities
>   preserved across an execve(2). A child created via fork(2) inherits
>   copies of its parent's capability sets. See below for a discussion of
>   the treatment of capabilities during exec(). Using capset(2), a thread
>   may manipulate its own capability sets, or, if it has the CAP_SETPCAP
>   capability, those of a thread in another process.